# What data structure should I use to accept any type of object and allow grouping based on its different properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-structures

For example, I have employee data that looks like

[image]

I want to allow grouping the data based on one or multiple columns like Role, role and experience, role and technology etc.

In C#, I can do this easily using LINQ but by asking this question, I want to understand how LINQ [EDITed] manipulates the data internally. If you can point me to some source where I can know more about this then it'll be great.

Edit: [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) (WPF) is very close to what I am trying to achieve. It takes a collection and group descriptors and returns a collection with appropriate grouping.

Edit2: During an offline discussion, someone said that it is done via trees. I'll update this when I have a concrete solution.

Comment: LINQ does not store data. LINQ is a way you write quick logic to access the data. You store the data in data structure like: List<T> or Dictionary<T, K> etc. and then you can write LINQ to access data from these.

Comment: LINQ does not store data, it queries it.  
LINQ to objects is a set of exetnsion methods for Enumerable.  
If you want to know how it works, you can [read it's source code.](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.Core/System/Linq)

Answer (score 4):

**LINQ does not store data.**

[Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) - way to manipulate your (predefined) data.

You must to define your class with fields, properties and method and than you can use LINQ to group, filter and sort data.

For example:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

//...

var users = new List<Employee>();
//fill users

var filteredUsers = users.Where(o=>o.Name.Contains("a")).ToList();
```

Comment: I was starting to write something similar, saw your post and converted mine to a comment. +1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you can add something - you are welcome

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, perhaps I need to describe my problem better. Say I want to write my own api where I'll accept a List of any object like List<Employee> or List<CustomType> and then I want to group the data in this list based on the different properties. How would I do this manipulation in the most optimized way? CollectionViewSource does similar things in WPF.